# Узнать временную зону пользователя на js

Tags: javascript, timezone

Есть страница с новостями и у каждой новости дата в Unix, она ставится на js как можно узнать временную зону по времени на компьютере пользователя?

Comment: Это `x = new Date(); x.getTimezoneOffset();` ?

Comment: Да, спасибо это :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У встроенного класса `Date` в JavaScript есть функция для получения смещения текущей временной зоны.

```
x = new Date();
x.getTimezoneOffset();
```